# How can I pass a variable name to an enum to return a value?

Tags: c++, enums

In C++, is it possible to pass a variable to a function to call an enum and return a value from the enum?

If this is a common question, I apologize, I'm new to C++ and might be using the wrong keywords when I search.

The compile error I receive is:

> Compilation error: cannot convert 'String' to 'getValue' in initialization

```
enum getValue 
{ 
    monday = 20, 
    tuesday = 30, 
    wednesday = 40, 
    thursday = 50, 
    friday = 60, 
    saturday = 70, 
    sunday = 80, 
    everyday = 90   
};

String settingValue(String settingName)
{
    getValue value = settingName;
    // getValue value = monday; <-- this works, although I'd like to call it with settingName instead of the hard coded text
    return value;
}
```

Comment: you want to eg `settingValue("friday")` to return `getValue::friday` ?

Comment: `if (settingName == "monday") { return monday; } else if ...`

Comment: (I've updated the original post) I'd like to call it with the variable name representing the hard coded value, rather than using the hard coded value, so that it can be used inside of a function. I am trying to replace the if/else if ladder I have because of ram size constraints and I've never used an enum before.

Comment: @Bbb Identifiers in code (the name of things) is completely unrelated to character strings. These identifiers typically don't even exist anymore in your compiled program. You need to define your own mapping in some way, for example with a `if` chain or by creating a constant `std::map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do it :

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string_view>
#include <map>
#include <optional>

enum day_value 
{ 
    monday = 20, 
    tuesday = 30, 
    wednesday = 40, 
    thursday = 50, 
    friday = 60, 
    saturday = 70, 
    sunday = 80, 
    everyday = 90   
};

// return optional to be able to indicate the setting name did not exist
std::optional<day_value> settingValue(std::string_view settingName)
{
    static std::map<std::string_view,day_value> map
    {
        {"monday",day_value::monday},
        {"tuesday",day_value::tuesday}
        //... add al your days here. You can also add "duplicates" for alternative spelling. e.g. "Monday"
    };

    std::optional<day_value> retval;
    if ( map.contains(settingName) ) 
    { 
        retval = map.at(settingName);
    }
    
    return retval;
}

int main()
{
    auto no_value = settingValue("dummy");
    assert(!no_value.has_value()); // setting value not found

    auto monday = settingValue("monday");
    assert(monday == day_value::monday);
}
```

Comment: ...and you could pass in a different `Pred` into the `std::map` declaration for case-insensitive conversion. Note that `contains` is C++20 onwards; prior to that use `count` and rely on an implicit conversion to `bool`.